# Does armature flux move when the position of brushes in a loaded DC generator are adjusted? If so, what happens to the original resultant flux?

Tags: generator

Based on my readings, a loaded DC generator creates both a main flux from the field poles and an armature flux that is perpendicular to the main flux. This causes a resultant flux at an angle. Because the magnetic neutral axis is perpendicular to the resultant flux, it will shift by an angle. This will cause sparking in the brushes.

[image]

To remedy this, the brushes are moved to the magnetic neutral axis. Going by the labels, a "armature flux" is present in the direction of the new magnetic neutral axis. It can be broken down into components. The x component is known as the demagnetizing flux and the y component is the cross magnetizing flux.

[image]

What I don't get is, is the armature flux from Picture 2 the new armature flux that is suppose to replace the first one? If so, won't the new armature flux and original main pole flux create a new resultant causing the magnetic neutral axis to change yet again?

Yes, I know that is a stupid idea and I am aware it is wrong. Because I am fully convinced of the concept that adjusting the position of brushes to the magnetic neutral axis does remedy a loaded DC generator. However, I really don't get how both pictures seem to use the armature flux and for me it implies that you shift the armature flux. It causes confusion for me because I think of the idea that the resultant flux is suppose to change.

It is possible that the armature flux that both pictures have the same notation for are suppose to mean different things. That might be the case. But I don't know exactly why and how. I decided to ask this question because almost all armature reaction discussions involve this concept and visualization and I can't seem to get an answer for my question. It might be best here since there is a little more analysis done by the people here rather than resorting to looking at the textbook.

Comment: It seems to me that you need to include a link to the source of the pictures and hopefully there will be text that explains it to you.

Comment: The text was not enough for me. That is from Electrical Technology by Theraja pages 939 and 940.

Comment: Unless you can provide an on-line link it's not answerable to anyone not in possession of that book. So, I would try and find an equivalent article on-line or post the accompanying text.

Comment: Your idea that "the new armature flux and original main pole flux create a new resultant causing the magnetic neutral axis to change yet again" may be correct. However the interactions have a single ultimate effect. The ultimate effect depends on the machine design and the actual load. You are essentially asking us to provide a version of the textbook explanation that is more complete or easier for you to understand. We can not do that. In the book that I am looking at, that is 3 pages and 3 diagrams and it is preceded by many pages of supporting material. You may need to consult other texts.

Comment: Can I ask, why does the alignment of brushes to the first shifted neutral axis produce lesser spark? Can a  watered down explanation be that it is a good estimate near the next shifted neutral axis? It always bothered me how it seems like that axis was perfect for the brushes. But thank you for the explanation that armature current does indeed depend on the brush position.

Comment: Sparking is the result of the brushes first shorting part of the armature winding and then reversing the voltage across that part. The inductance of the winding causes it to develop a voltage to keep the current constant in the original direction. With brushes at the "true neutral" brush position considering armature reaction, the effect of the armature winding inductance is minimized . The "true neutral position" is not a fixed angle. It is shifted by changing the motor load.